# How to retain authorization with googlesheets4 as it always assumes I'm in a non interactive session and won't write my output to sheets?

Tags: r, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

I am unable to (1) automate reports that I'm trying to export to directly to google sheets & (2), even when I go through manually the warning (see below) does not believe it's an interactive session even after I restart my session or terminate R and return at a later time.

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/googlesheets4", force = TRUE)
library(googlesheets4)
library(googledrive)
library(gargle)
library(httr)
options(httr_oob_default=TRUE) 
options(gargle_oauth_email = "XYZ@gmail.com")
drive_auth()
MKPI <- list(OVR_KPI_DF,M_KPI,R_KPI,U_KPI,C_KPI)
sheets_auth()
sheets_create(
  paste(currentDate,"_Master_KPI_Review",sep=""),
  sheets = MKPI
)

Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `sheets_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
  * Call `sheets_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
```

Comment: It's not assuming that you are in a non-interactive session. The authentication is failing and it is asking you whether that might be because you're in a non-interactive session. Does the call to `sheets_auth` succeed? Do you get a browser pop-up and did you log in successfully?

Comment: It does not. This morning I was having success getting the pop up but the token was not being accepted and i was getting this same error

Comment: Hello @WolfofTinStreet, are you using a **valid token** for your request? Cheers!